# How to get the actual [UIScreen mainScreen] frame size?

Tags: uiview, frame, uiapplication

I'm a bit annoyed. I have an app with the statusbar visible in the main window. Since I would like to setup my views and their frame sizes dynamically (perhaps the status bar takes up 40 pixels during a phone call, for example).

I can do one of the two:

```
[[UIScreen mainScreen] bounds];
[[UIScreen mainScreen] applicationFrame];
```

The really annoying this is these two output two different sets of values, each equally as useless.

`bounds` will output: `{{0, 0}, {320, 480}}` while
`applicationFrame` will output `{{0, 20}, {320, 460}}`

As you can see, `bounds` gives the correct y origin (0 starts from right below the statusbar) but then gives a height of 480, which is incorrect. It should be 460, since the statusbar is visible. Then we have `applicationFrame` which starts 20 pixels below the statusbar (so there's a cap), but then gives the correct height. But that's not very useful when it's then pushed down 20 pixels anyway.

Any help?

Comment: specially useful when dealing with the iPhone 5.

Comment: it's perfectly correct and good.  Bounds in this case is the physical glass screen, and applicationFrame is just that without the statusbar. Just to be clear, they are both in the **SAME coordinates**, the "glass" coordinates.  So the bounds start (obviously!) at zero, whereas the application frame starts where the statusbar ends - at one after 19, ie, at 20!

Comment: CGPoint p = [[UIScreen mainScreen] bounds].origin; CGSize s = [[UIScreen mainScreen] applicationFrame].size; CGRectMake(p.x, p.y, s.width, s.height); If you really want the origin of one and the size of the other.

Answer (score 50, accepted):

Actually that is very usefull.
When you ask a `UIScreen` for it's `Bounds` you get the bounds of the screen, which is the whole device screen.  (the status bar is part of the screen)
But if you ask a `UIScreen` to tell you where and how big can be the root view of your application asking for the `applicationFrame` is usefull. 
There is no direct relationship between the 2 calls except that the `applicationFrame` is returned in the `UIScreen bounds` coordinate system. (But the status bar is not part of your application, that explain the different result)

> [applicationFrame](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/ipad/#documentation/uikit/reference/UIScreen_Class/Reference/UIScreen.html)
>   The frame rectangle to use for your application’s window. (read-only)
>   @property(nonatomic, readonly) CGRect applicationFrame
>   Discussion
>   This property contains the screen bounds minus the area occupied by the status bar, if it is visible. Using this property is the recommended way to retrieve your application’s initial window size. The rectangle is specified in points.

Comment: I get `460` for `[[UIScreen mainScreen] applicationFrame].size.height` on iPhone 4 with iOS7 (No phone call, hotspot, or anything that changes the status bar height...). `bounds` gives me `480` for `height`...

Comment: @AvielGross Thanks, I don't recall in what way I stumble upon that being different in iOS7 (maybe it was with a pre-release version of iOS 7, or in a very bad Dream...), but I was not able to reproduce it today, so I've update my answer. Thanks again for the correction.

Answer (score 8):

Actually 0 does not start at the bottom of the status bar. It starts at the top of it. Add a UILabel at (0,0) and you won't see it unless you have the status bar hidden. So bounds gives you the total screen area, and applicationFrame gives you the area your application has to work with. I bet if you hide the status bar the application frame will match the bounds.

Answer (score 1):

I had a similar issue. What I was doing was pretty dumb, but I hope this helps someone.

In the subview I had:

```
- (id)initWithFrame:(CGRect)frame
{
    self = [super initWithFrame:frame];
    if (self) {
        UIView * otherSubview = [[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:frame];
        [self addSubview:otherSubview];
    }
    return self;
}
```

Because I was creating my subview with a frame with an origin *not at* (0,0), but then using that same frame to generate subviews for my subview, those subviews also got shifted down. The result was that annoying black banner you mentioned.

I fixed this by doing the following:

```
- (id)initWithFrame:(CGRect)frame
{
    self = [super initWithFrame:frame];
    if (self) {
        CGRect rect = frame;
        rect.origin.x = 0;
        rect.origin.y = 0;
        UIView * otherSubview = [[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:rect];
        [self addSubview:otherSubview];
    }
    return self;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You might look at UIWindow. It inherits from UIView so it will have bounds and a frame, and iOS apps are all single window.  -[UIApplication keyWindow] will return the window set up by the app delegate.  Since all other views are anchored in the main window, I imagine this ought to give you correct bounds.

Answer (score 0):

Swift 2.0  update:

```
func presentAboveAll() {
       //Get the view from the nib. Assuming the view is is in AboveAllView.xib
        let nibContents = NSBundle.mainBundle().loadNibNamed("AboveAllView", owner: nil, options: nil)

        //Get hold of your view
        let views =  nibContents.filter {
          if let _ = $0 as? UIView{
            return true
          }
          return false
        }

        guard views.count > 0  else {
          return
        }

        //Set up frame and add to the app's key window
        let view  = views.first as! UIView
        view.frame = UIScreen.mainScreen().bounds
        UIApplication.sharedApplication().keyWindow?.addSubview(view)
}
```