# Setting frame of UIScrollView sitting between Nav/Tab bars

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, uiscrollview

As the title explains, I'm creating a UIScrollView programmatically in my view controller's loadView, which I will then set to self.view.

```
_pagingScrollView = [[UIScrollView alloc] initWithFrame:[[UIScreen mainScreen] bounds]];
self.view = _pagingScrollView;
```

If I inspect _pagingScrollView.frame at the end of loadView, it's equal to

{{0,0}, {320,480}}.

However, if I inspect the same property within my `scrollViewDidScroll` delegate, it switches to

{{0,0},{320,367}}

How do I alloc/init my scrollView so that it's height takes the tab/nav bars into account from the beginning, and gives me 367? I know I could simply hard code 367, but I'd like to know what's going on here and why it starts out with one value and then changes.

Answer (score 1):

Why not create the `UIScrollView` with known bounds

```
_pagingScrollView = [[UIScrollView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0,0,320,387];
```

or subtract the height of TabBar or NavBar from `UIScreen` bounds

Answer (score 0):

I believe the problem you're seeing is caused by your use of [UIScreen mainscreen] which refers to the whole window (320,480) and doesn't care about the Nav/Tab views inside of it.

Rather than using that, you may instead desire to use the applicationFrame method.

See this related post -- [How to get the actual [UIScreen mainScreen] frame size?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5150794/how-to-get-the-actual-uiscreen-mainscreen-frame-size)

Additionally, if your vc's superView/superViewController are set, you could use those to get more relevant size information, because the MainScreen will still only refer to the *whole* window, and not take sub view controllers, like nav/tabs into account.