# iPhone4 UI design vs iPhone5

Tags: iphone, ios, user-interface, uiimage

I have a next problem. I was searching in Google and here but still not found correct and proper solution. I have application which has to run on iPhone 4 and on iPhone 5. As we know iPhone 5 has a different screen size then 4th one. Let's see simple case, I have a view controller with background image. Image is size sensitive and if I will stretch it it will look ugly. So I have two different images one image for old 4th resolution and and another image for new 5th one. The question is what is the best and let's say "native" way to implement correct image showing on the both devices.

I see simplest way to do it is making runtime checking which device currently used and set proper image name to UIImageView. But I find it ugly. Does somebody know the correct way to do it?

Answer (score 2):

You can use:

```
#define IS_IPHONE5 (([[UIScreen mainScreen] bounds].size.height-568)?NO:YES)
```

Then,

```
if (IS_IPHONE5) {
//iPhone5
} else {
/older devices
}
```

Source: [How to get the actual [UIScreen mainScreen] frame size?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5150794/how-to-get-the-actual-uiscreen-mainscreen-frame-size)